# Instantiation in a for loop - js

Tags: javascript

I want to instantiate a Column per header title in a 'headers' array, like so:

column.js

```
class Column{
   constructor(column_name){
      this.name = column_name
   }
}
```

index.js

```
const Column = require('./Column.js')

let columns = []

console.log(headers) // ['Name', 'Address', 'Phone']
headers.forEach( function(header){
   columns.push( new Column(`${header}`) )
})

console.log(columns) //[]
```

However, no Columns are actually getting instantiated when I check the columns array. Not sure what's happening or how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like a lot depends on what's in that `headers` array.

Comment: My guess is that `headers` is empty (fairly sure that's Pointy's guess too).

Comment: This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bs4q15cc/) confirms the code works, so must be an issue as described in the comments above, or some other code you haven't shown.

Comment: Code should work, see http://imgur.com/a/tvpSP
Check your `require('./Column') // btw. you don't need .js here`

Comment: @hinok There are better ways to show code than posting a screenshot :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try putting this below the `Column` class definition:

```
export default Column;
```

JS modules aren't like, say, Python modules which in their simplest invocation just allow you to import an entire file's namespace. Instead, `import` only allows you to see values which have explicitly been `export`ed, and sometimes you'll find yourself narrowing that scope down still further. Check out the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

In this case you should've been seeing `TypeError: Column is not a constructor`, giving you a clue to check what happens when you define `Column` in the same file (which does work as another user pointed out).